# Make the caption table at below of word "TABLE #"

Tags: tables, captions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{This is example of table. abcdefghijkl This is example of table. This is example of table. This is example of table. This is example of table. This is example of table.}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        No&Alphabet\\
        \hline
        1&a\\
        2&b\\
        3&c\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How to make the caption table like below? I don't have an idea to do it.

[image]

```
TABLE #
CAPTION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own style for the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{par}{\par}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{Wijaya}{\hfil\MakeUppercase{#1}\space \Roman{table}}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{sc}{{\scshape #1}}
\captionsetup{labelsep=par, labelformat=Wijaya, textformat=sc}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{This is example of table. abcdefghijkl This is example of table. This is example of table. This is example of table. This is example of table. This is example of table.}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            No&Alphabet\\
            \hline
            1&a\\
            2&b\\
            3&c\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]